# If statement does not seem to be working properly

Tags: javascript

I am working on a real estate site and would like to have specific pages to show properties for rent/sale. I am trying to only show properties that have the "Rent" status, but the if statement seems to just default to else.

*Using border styles to visibly see if statements.*

web page: http://targetrealtygroupdev.com/rent/

What am I missing?

```
<div class="property-item">
 <div class="proprty-inner>
  <div class="property-status-bg">
   "Rent"
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

```
    .one {
     border: 1px solid red;
    }
    .two {
     border: 1px solid blue;
    }   
     <script>
          document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
            var status = document.getElementsByClassName("property-status-bg");
             for (item of status) { 
              var type = item.innerText;
               if (type == 'Rent') {
                jQuery('.property-item').addClass('one');
               } else {
                jQuery('.property-item').addClass('two');
               }
             }
          });
     </script>
```

Comment: Examine the DOM. The content is `"Rent` with a leading `"`. Looks like typo question.

Comment: Why mix DOM and jQuery?

Comment: you are missing to show the HTML concerned part of this code

Comment: You select all the elements, not the current one that you had with rent.

Comment: @MisterJojo .property-item is each individual property. The status is the little tag on each property that reads "Sale" or "Rent" that I loop to get the individual strings. Does that help? I very much rusty with js

Comment: @MisterJojo no. `.property-item` is each property item in the grid. `status` is just a variable I used to get the innerText from the `property-status-bg` tag inside the `.property-item`

Comment: @MisterJojo

`<div class="property-item"><div class="property-inner"><div class"property-status-bg">"Rent"</div></div></div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are changing **all** `jQuery('.property-item')` for each item
and `.property-status-bg` is not only with a simple text == 'Rent' or 'Sale' ...
it's look like:

```html
<p>
  <span class="property-status-bg" style="background-color: #888">
    Rent
    <span class="property-arrow" style="border-left-color: #888; border-right-color: #888"></span>
  </span>
</p>
```

So you have to use the [string.include](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) method

try:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event)
  { 
  document.querySelectorAll('.property-status-bg').forEach(item =>
    {
    let ClassChoice = item.textContent.includes('Rent')  ? 'one' : 'two'
    item.closest('.property-item').classList.add( ClassChoice )
    })
  })
```

Comment: yep this worked. I had no idea `.closest` existed. appreciate you putting up with me. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting all the elements, you are not selecting the one you are referencing in the loop.

```
item.closest('.property-item').classList.add('one');
```